Compiling on vscode with the codeblocks mingw compiler
How do i compile c/c++ code on vscode if i already have the mingw that installed with code blocks.
i tried looking up on the internet but couldn't find anything for my specific situation, i dont even now how i got here to be honest.

why do you need code::blocks if you are using VS Code? are you using its buildsystem?

You can't expect to receive an answer if you just provide such information!
